# Using Azure with Ninject InSessionScope class in an MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ninject

I have a few classes that are instantiated using ninject "Session Scoping" - because these objects get passed between controller methods and then only get persisted once, this technique worked well for this project.

With Azure's multi-hosting capabilities I assume that InSessionScope is no longer reliable because any of the servers could be servicing my request.

Does anyone know if I am wrong and can still use Session Scoping with Azure or does anyone know of an alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you would use a custom session state provider that works with Windows Azure:

- [Session State Provider for Windows Azure Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx)
- [Azure Providers](http://azureproviders.codeplex.com/)

Now if you use a session state provider other than InProc, you'll need to make sure that whatever you store in session is [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx). You should test this since this might have an impact on how your application works today.